# Пустая очередь проверок при индикаторе в 3

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Заметил уже как ~месяц висит уведомление в шапке с кол-вом правок для обработки не соответствующее действительности. То есть очередь правок абсолютно пустая, а в шапке висит число **3**.

[image]

Comment: Старайтесь пользоваться imgur для картинок: там hot linking разрешён. Кроме того, вы можете просто перетащить картинку на форму добавления вопроса, и картинка будет залита автоматически.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вижу уведомление о собственных правках, ждущих в очереди](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b6%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8). Там вопрос другой, но ответ в том числе и на этот вопрос.

Comment: посмотрите возможное объяснение http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1933/177221

Comment: @PashaPash похоже на правду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это число отражает число проверок не для вас лично, а *для всего сайта*. Кроме того, оно *кэшируется*. Оно предназначено не для точного отражения текущей ситуации и доступности конкретно вам в очереди каких-либо проверок, а служит банальным призывом не забывать про проверки. На счётчик стоит обращать внимание, только если число достигает больших значений.

На большом СО, где проблема заполненных очередей и, соответственно, призывы с ними разобраться наиболее актуальны, счётчик никогда не приближается к нулю, поэтому конкретные цифры не имеют значения.

В целом, это by design.

Comment: Для моей логики это очень странное решение

Comment: @korytoff Получение числа для каждого пользователя — это очень ресурсоёмкая задача. Сайт загнётся, он только и будет, что считать проверки. Текущее решение — компромисс.

Comment: Тут я могу с вами поспорить, насчет ресурсоёмкости задачи. На скрине видны кол-во проверок по конкретным категориям доступные конкретному пользователю, соответственно для общего числа их нужно просто просуммировать. Сумма *n* слагаемых (в данном случае 6) очень ресурсоёмкая задача?

Comment: @korytoff Эту страницу вы видите, если вы открываете конкретно её. В этот момент совершаются все сложные расчёты. А счётчик отображается всегда, на всех страницах. И пересчёт нужно будет совершать при каждом переходе на странице, если состояние хотя бы одной проверки изменилось.